# Algorithm suggestion: comparing sound clips

Tags: algorithm, audio, artificial-intelligence

(Not sure if this is the right place for this question)

We are analyzing thousands of sound clips of people talking in an attempt to find patterns in the pitch, syllable rate, etc. in order to come up with a signature database to match new sound bites to emotions.

While I am familiar with some AI algorithms (Bayes, for instance) I'm curious if anyone has any ideas on the types of algorithms we could employ.

Overall concept (figure short 2-5 second .wav clips):

```
soundClip1 -> 'anger'
soundClip2 -> 'happy'
soundClip3 -> 'sad'
...
emotion = predict(newSoundClip)
```

Given a new sound clip, we would like to do something similar to Shazzam except for returning a probability that the clip represents a particular emotion.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Google Scholar will be your best friend.  What Mike Nakis implies, I will say straight out:  This is a significant research project which will require expertise in machine learning and may need substantial input from audiologists, speech professionals, psychologists etc.  Start with AVEC, the Audio Visual Emotion Challenge, which will be in its fifth year this year if they have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to normalize the clips in terms of their amplitude and frequency to make them comparable.

Then measure amplitude and spectral properties like variance, autocorrelation, number of minima/maxima, etc.

These measurements allow to view each clip as a vector in an n-dimensional space. You can use cluster analysis methods to find neighbored clips. Principal component analysis (PCA) might help to find more or less meaningful property dimensions.

It takes a lot of reading pattern recognition, signal processing and cluster analysis texts to get to know what is possible.

Comment: This sounds super close to exactly what I'm looking for. Visualizing an N-vector where each value corresponds to one component of a spectral analysis sounds super close to what I need. So ideally in trying to understand 10k+ audio clips that have been categorized, I would be looking for a set of properties (pitch, band narrowness, syllables per second, etc.) that all result in similar vectors?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You are basically training with clips of known semantic properties. Analyze what makes them different. The art is to tune the measurement dimensions in such a way, that they can be evaluated efficiently and still serve as reliable distinction criteriae (Google "vector quantizer"). The overall flow of work should be similar to OCR character recognition.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and say this is spot on. We are using a slightly modified version of the openSMILE framework and it is working wonderfully.